# floorspace do-while program

Tags: java, do-while

I am supposed to write a program that calculates the total floor space in a house. The program prompts the user to enter the length & width of at least one  room and it needs to verify with the user if he wants to enter more room dimensions.

It isn't working. Someone please help me?

```
import java.util.*;

public class FloorSpace
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double length = 0.0, width = 0.0, floorSpace = 0.0;
        char ans;


        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter length: ");
            length = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter width: ");
            width = input.nextDouble();

            floorSpace = length * width;

            floorSpace += floorSpace;

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more room dimensions? (y/n): ");
            ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }
        while (ans == 'y');


        System.out.println("\nTotal floor space is " + floorSpace);

    }
```

}

Oh my I just found out something's wrong with my computation formula. Can someone please help me.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: the IDE says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at FloorSpace.main(FloorSpace.java:28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `floorSpace` to `length * width` every time and then incrementing that value by itself (which is really just multiplying it by two).

Replace

```
floorSpace = length * width;

floorSpace += floorSpace;
```

with just

```
floorSpace += length * width
```

Comment: that's what Ive been looking for thank you for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ans= input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

use:

```
ans = input.next().charAt(0);
```

To fix your formula use:

```
    floorSpace += length * width;
```

and remove:

```
floorSpace = length * width;
```

So the final solution looks like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FloorSpace
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double length = 0.0, width = 0.0, floorSpace = 0.0;
        char ans;


        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter length: ");
            length = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter width: ");
            width = input.nextDouble();

            floorSpace += length * width;

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more room dimensions? (y/n): ");
            ans = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        while (ans == 'y');

        System.out.println("\nTotal floor space is " + floorSpace);
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be working but it won't give the right answer with that code. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FloorSpace
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double length = 0.0, width = 0.0, floorSpace = 0.0;
        char ans='n'; //not for default


        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter length: ");
            length = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter width: ");
            width = input.nextDouble();



            floorSpace +=  length * width;

            System.out.print("Do you want to enter more room dimensions? (y/n): ");
            if (input.hasNext()){
                ans = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        while (ans == 'y');


        System.out.println("\nTotal floor space is " + floorSpace);

    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Bro i have a question. What's the if (input.hasNext()) line for? Although it still produced the same result. Thanks

Comment: Prevent if not exist a input (the operation next() may be null)